# Is it possible to show context menu for range of items selection in datagridview using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview, contextmenu

Is it possible to show context menu for range of items selection in datagridview using c#. In general we can show context menu when select any item and right-click on mouse.
Similarly can we show same context menu for range of items (two or more items selection) in datagridview in windows application?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Don't ask me how until and unless you show what have you done so far

Comment: I have created a contexmenu with menu items and associated contextmenu id with control.I am not getting any idea how to apply this for range of items.

Comment: plz help me in this regard.

Comment: what do you mean by range of item? Show the code you've written

Comment: range of items mean selecting 2 or more items in datagridview and then right-click mouse then it has to show context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do. Assuming your DataGridView(DGv) is `dataGridView1` and ContextMenuStrip is `cms`

First set `MultiSelect` & `SelectionMode` property of the `DGv` to `true` & `FullRowSelect` respectively.

```
//capturing current mouse coordinate to diplay menu where the mouse pointer is. 
//MouseX & MouseY is an int variable and it's global to this class.
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    MouseX = e.X;
    MouseY = e.Y;
}

//Avoid row selection when Right Click. This is optional you can ignore this one if you want to select the Row on Right Click
private void dataGridView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right){
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = false;
    }
}

//Time to show the menu.
private void dataGridView2_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e){
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.RowIndex > -1){
            contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear(); //Since I am adding the menu items dynamically. I am clearing the previous menu to avoid repeatition. Ignore this step if your menu is static/predefined
            foreach(DataGridViewRow gr in dataGridView1.Rows){
                if(gr.Selected){
                 //if row is selected, I adding the Value of the First Cell as Menu Item
                 cms.Items.Add(gr.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                 cms.Items.Add("-"); //adding menu separator
                }
            }
            cms.Show(dataGridView1, new System.Drawing.Point(MouseX, MouseY)); //this will add First Cell Value of all selected Rows as menu item and display the Context Menu
        }
    }
```

I hope this suffice your requirement.